# excuting vim command silently then echo in vim

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I want to execute a shell command on `autocmd BufWrite` in my `.vimrc` , then echo (in vim) a message saying it's donem without showing the shell.

(basically `touch *.less`), then echo an information message saying "file touched !".

The first part works, but the 2nd command is executed in the shell instead of vim.

The command should be something like this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.less silent! !touch '%:p:h'/*.less | echo 'file  '.expand('%:p:h').' touched !'
```

I think I need a way to "ends" the command and allow an other command.

I tried this without more success:

```
:silent !touch '%:p:h'/*.less && exit 0 | unsilent! | echo "file touched"
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work if you past by a function :

```
function! Cmd()
    silent! execute '! touch %:p:h/*.less'
    echo 'file '.expand('%:p:h').' touched !'
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *.less call Cmd()
```

Comment: This works almost like I want (after a small syntax fix). When I do that I have the message `Press ENTER or type command to continue` which a little annoying. Any idea for that ? (by the way, welcome in stackoverflow :) )

Comment: Thanks ! :)
There are tricks to disable it : [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts)
But this is a necessary when you want to print and read something by a trigger..

Comment: Yes I found that, and added `redraw!` between the 2 lines, and moved `silent!` inside the execute command.

Answer (score 1):

If you call external command, with the leading `!`, `newline` is the end of the command, other chars, like `|`, will be a part of your external command, that is, it will be the shell pipe, and it won't be passed to vim's command. For this part, you can check `:h :!` for details.

```
A '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use
        it to append a Vim command.  See |:bar|.
```

If you want to combine two commands, one is external, one is vim. You can write a function to wrap the commands, or the following if you prefer shorter one-liner:

```
:exec "!shell command|shell|shell"|exec "vimcommand"
```

In this way, the pipe connects the two `exec` command.

An example you can try:

```
:exec "!echo 'foo'"|exec "echo 'bar'"
```

You will get `foo` in shell stdout and the `bar` in your vim.

Comment: I just found that solution and was going to answer it, but thanks you !  `:execute 'silent! !touch "%:p:h"/*.less' |echo "file touched"`. The silent part is missing

Comment: @Asenar yes, the key is making the unconnectable command "connectable" , put it in `exec`